# Most "Firestore-native" way for ESP32/Arduino to retrieve data from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arduino, google-cloud-functions, esp32

I am prototyping an IoT device that uses an ESP32 dev module (Arduino framework) and Google Cloud Firestore for its database. Firestore works great when you can use the Google-provided SDKs (for example when designing a mobile or web app), but I have been finding it far more difficult to figure out an elegant way to connect Firestore to the ESP32.

My current implementation involves a Google Cloud Function, the code for which is below. It creates a REST API that my ESP32 can call every 10 seconds or so. When the ESP32 hits the API, the Cloud Function performs the Firestore query and returns the result to the ESP32 in JSON format.

Is there a better way to do this for resource-constrained devices that can't use the Firestore SDKs? The idea of blindly calling the cloud function every 10 seconds seems hacky. Does anyone know of a more "Firestore-native" way to do this? Is there some way to open a web socket/stream on the ESP32 that updates whenever data is updated on Firestore?

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const userApp = express();
userApp.use(cors({origin: true}));

userApp.get('/:id/updates', async (req, res) => {
    const userDoc = await db.collection('users').doc(req.params.id).get();
    const userSettingsData = userDoc.data().userSettings;
    
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({"userSettings": {...userSettingsData}}));
});

exports.user = functions.https.onRequest(userApp);
```

Comment: Make use of the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest) directly that the SDKs use?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [streaming capabilities of the Realtimedatabase REST](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/03/announcing-streaming-for-firebase-rest.html) API to solve those repeated calls every 10 secconds. Just create a cloud function that updates a single value in the realtimedatabase (for example a timestamp for the last update) and listen on your device on that change with a stream. When a change happens call cour cloud function. That way it would be called only when something happend.

Answer (score 0):

The google-prescribed method for connecting embedded devices with the cloud is the IoT Core and (on the embedded side) [Google Cloud IoT Device SDK for Embedded C](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c) which provides a resource-efficient MQTT pipe between them. Note that Espressif has a [port of mentioned SDK](https://github.com/espressif/esp-google-iot) for ESP32, but it's natively for ESP-IDF framework, not Arduino. I have first-hand experience using it on ESP-IDF and I suspect it'll integrate just fine into Arduino as well.

Using IoT Core to talk to embedded devices requires a bit of extra work on the cloud side, namely you need to plumb your desired data between the Firestore and IoT Core. This should be fairly simple, though, e.g. using pubsub. The documentation and API integration on cloud side is generally excellent, so I wouldn't fear this work.

Comment: Thanks Tarmo, this seems like the answer I was looking for. Is MQTT the proper protocol to use for a "one user, one device" consumer IoT device? I had heard of IoT Core/pubsub, and even tried to copy the demo that starts at 18:15 [here](https://youtu.be/7kpE44tXQak), but it seems like MQTT is primarily geared toward applications where all devices subscribe and report to the same "channel," for example a network of sensors that all feed into one dashboard. Am I misunderstanding MQTT's intended use case? Is it common to have hundreds or thousands of MQTT topics for each user's individual device?

Comment: MQTT is just the underlying implementation, IoT Core uses it to give you a good, clean interface on the cloud side for bidirectional data exchange with the device (which is very coveniently compatible with pubsub-like concepts). It can also do HTTPS if you wish, but this is a less optimal protocol for the same task. The cloud-side IoT Core interface remains the same in either case. Anyway, how you architect your cloud solution is up to you. You certainly want each physical device to subscribe to a minimal amount of topics, perhaps 2-5. You'd filter/generate topics as needed on the cloud side.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ESP-IDF framework for your development you can use this ESP-IDF component to directly communicate with Firestore REST API via HTTPS without requiring a cloud function:

- https://github.com/kaizoku-oh/firestore.git